# Reverse filtering order in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, collection, layered-navigation

I have a custom filter attribute named *User weight less than* at my fitness stuff site.

[image: screenshot]

The problem is that my clients wants to see products filtered by *User weight more than*

How can I get this?

I'm running Magento 1.9.10 and Ves Superstore theme.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Can you explain the logic behight "User weight more than" and "User weight less than"? It is not clear to me what the attribute values mean and how you want the filter to behave

Comment: OK, thanks for your feedback.
For example I have a threadmill category. If the user of my site use filter "User weight less than 95 kg", he would get all threadmills which may be used аt 95 kg or less load values.Despite this my customers wants to see all threadmills with capacity 95 kg and more, 100 kg and more and so on?
It is possible implement such kind of feature in Magento CRM?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a second attribute
- fill it automatically based on values of the old one
- hide the old one
- use the new one to filter